# User model error after Laravel update (Class User contains 3 abstract method)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

After I update my laravel using composer update, I got this

```
"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException",
"message":"Class User contains 3 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Illuminate\\Auth\\UserInterface::setRememberToken, Illuminate\\Auth\\UserInterface::getRememberTokenName, Illuminate\\Auth\\Reminders\\RemindableInterface::getReminderEmail)",
"file":"D:\app\\models\\User.php",
"line":54
```

error when authenticating.

Comment: Please post the contents of that file around line 54. That might help...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This error happened because of the [latest commit](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/f138f0f4fce63fdb371064a66a4c92226a8b1ace).

You can check the upgrade documentation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade#upgrade-4.1.26), to fix this issue.

As stated, add the following to your `User.php` model class:

```
public function getRememberToken()
{
    return $this->remember_token;
}

public function setRememberToken($value)
{
    $this->remember_token = $value;
}

public function getRememberTokenName()
{
    return 'remember_token';
}
```

Comment: Also you have to add `remember_token varchar(255)` field to your users table.

Comment: For some reason the confide migration generator isn't adding the remember_token for me. You have to put it in manually. Make it nullable. In schema builder: `$table->string('remember_token')->nullable()->index();`

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me by adding the below to `app/User`

```
 public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }
    /**
     * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }
```

Example `app/User`

```
 <?php

namespace App;

use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the identifier that will be stored in the subject claim of the JWT.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }
    /**
     * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```